# Get Client's information like MyDomain\Username in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried using the following codes to get my clients info **(MyDomain\Username):**

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"];
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();

Page.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
```

All of them works fine, well atleast on my localhost. But when i deployed it in our server,
and tried to access it in our intranet those codes return the info of the SERVER Machine, not the client's machine.

PS: the authentication mode is Windows and The IIS is also in windows auth...

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/36e1bcfa-a46a-47a8-8b21-78357efe866b/how-to-get-windows-login-credentials-using-cnet)

Comment: Thanks for the that, but that code returns the IIS name.

Comment: Are you using impersonation or anonymous auth ?

Comment: i don't know about impersonation, but im sure that i disabled the anonymous auth.

Comment: look into IIS, in the authentification, what's active ? only windows auth ?

Comment: Yes. Only integrated windows auth is enabled. BTW im using IIS 5.0